"Instantiation of new objects and access to static classes or parameters is forbidden" error with th:action
I'm working on a Spring Boot application using Thymeleaf for the view layer. In one of my templates, I need to create a form for updating a book. However, I'm encountering the following error when rendering the template:
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Instantiation of new objects and access to static classes or parameters is forbidden in this context (template: "book-change" - line 12, col 7)

Here is the relevant code in my Thymeleaf template (book-change.html):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Change book</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Change book</h1>
    <a th:href="@{/admin}">Admin panel</a>
    <h2>Book</h2>

    <form method="post" th:object="${bookToChange}" th:action="@{'/admin/changeBook/' + ${param.id}}">
      <label>
        Title:
        <input type="text" th:field="*{title}" placeholder="Title"/>
      </label>
      <label>
        Author:
        <input type="text" th:field="*{author}" placeholder="Author"/>
      </label>
      <label>
        Year:
        <input type="number" th:field="*{year}" placeholder="Year"/>
      </label>
      <label>
        Keywords:
        <input type="text" th:field="*{keywords}" placeholder="Keywords"/>
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Change Book</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

param.id is passed correctly, and I've confirmed that it contains the expected value because it renders properly elsewhere in the template.
I've tried to add id through Model and it worked, but I don't think this is the best way, as Thymeleaf makes it possible to get the parameters from the URL.

I've replaced th:action with this:
th:action="@{/admin/changeBook/{id}(id=${param.id})}"


And that solved your problem?
